# How to enable the _Generic keyword

Tags: c++11

I have this test source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;

    printf("x=%d\n", _Generic('x', int: 1, default: 0));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with c++ (from GCC 4.9.2) fails:

```
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:7:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  printf("x=%d\n", _Generic('x', int: 1, default: 0));
                                 ^
t.cpp:7:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘default’
  printf("x=%d\n", _Generic('x', int: 1, default: 0));
                                         ^
t.cpp:7:51: error: ‘_Generic’ was not declared in this scope
  printf("x=%d\n", _Generic('x', int: 1, default: 0));
```

The compiler arguments are:

```
c++ --std=c++11 t.cpp -o t
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use C code in C++, use templates instead

Comment: Or compile with a C compiler

Answer (score 4):

`_Generic` is a C11 feature. It is not present in C++ (any version at least up to C++14 - I don't really expect it to be added either).

If you want to use it, you'll need to write C code, and use a compiler that supports that standard (reasonably recent versions of gcc and clang do for example, using `-std=c11`).

If you want to write C++, use overloading or templates instead, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int)  { return 1; }
int foo(char) { return 0; }

int main()
{
  std::cout << "x=" << foo('x') << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `x=0` in C++, the `foo(char)` overload is the best match.

Note that there's difference between C and C++ that might trick you here too: `'x'` is a char in C++. It's an `int` in C. So if `_Generic` had been implemented (maybe as an extension) by your compiler, chances are you'd get different output when compiling your example as C versus compiling as C++.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the C++ form (forgive me for using the using directive, I know its bad form):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< typename T> T do_something(T argument) {
  // Put here what you need
}

int main()
{
        int x;

        cout << "x" << (x = do_something(x));
        return 0;
}
```

_Generic is C11, you're probably using a C++ compiler when you meant to use a C compiler.